# Найти и вывести отличающиеся строки в двух файлах

Tags: linux, ubuntu, консоль, dpkg

Нужна помощь в создании консольной команды.

Мне нужно получить список пакетов через `dpkg --list > /folder/name.txt`, потом сравнить пакеты на разных серверах, и в отдельном файле описать, какие пакеты не дублируются.

То есть сравнить, увидеть, что пакеты в двух файлах отличаются, и описать в файл `name1.txt` — какие пакеты отличаются.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### получение

команда:

```
$ dpkg-query -W
```

выдаст список установленных (и удалённых, но для которых сохранена конфигурация) пакетов в виде: `имя версия`.

если версии не важны, можно выводить только имена:

```
$ dpkg-query -W -f '${package}\n'
```

для сравнения списков сохранять лучше сразу в отсортированном виде:

```
$ ... | sort > list
```

### сравнение

собственно сравнение списков можно делать разными программами (и с разными опциями, по-разному представляющими результат).

например, с помощью программы **`comm`**.

уникальные строки из обоих файлов вместе (строка `aria2` присутствует только во вторм файле, а `screen` — только в первом).

```
$ comm -3 list1 list2
       aria2
screen
```

уникальные строки из первого файла:

```
$ comm -2 -3 list1 list2
screen
```

уникальные строки из второго:

```
$ comm -1 -3 list1 list2
aria2
```

---

или, например, с помощью программы **`diff`**

```
$ diff -y --suppress-common-lines list1 list2
                                      > aria2
screen                                <
```

---

**дополнение про подсчёт количества**

подсчитать количество строк, возвращаемых программой/командой в стандартный поток вывода (*stdout*), можно, например, программой `wc` с опцией `-l`:

```
$ ... | wc -l
1
```

Comment: спасибо за ваш ответ. попробую и отпишусь.

Comment: Попробывал ваш вариант, мне не подходит. Мне нужно чтобы выдавались различия в файлах. Я не знаю какие там различия и задать их не могу. Я подразумеваю что программа сама выдаст мне различия. т.е есть 2 файла dpkglist1 и dpkglist2 в них различия в количистве пакетов. вот мне нужно получить вывод в файл какие пакеты разные в обоих файлах.

Comment: *какие пакеты разные* — что **именно** вы имеете ввиду? разные версии? тогда используйте первую из команд для получения списка: `dpkg-query -W`

Comment: имеется ввиду список установленных пакетов. на одном сервере их больше на другом меньше. у меня есть 2 файла со списком. сделать сравнение пакетов и вывести в файл различие между ними.

Comment: в каком виде вы хотите видеть «различие между ними»?

Comment: дополните, пожалуйста, ваш вопрос примером желаемого результата.

Comment: Извените заработался. Хочу видеть вывод в файле: dpkglist1 содержит 10 записей отличных от dpkglist2. в другом файле наоборот (к примеру) dpkglist2 содержит 20 записей отличимых от файла dpkglist1. и соответственно эти записи выведены в отдельном файле. Задача простая, возможно я не правельно выражаюсь и вам не понятен ход моих мыслей. Задача стоит такакая. Узнать различия пакетов на серверах. На одном стоит freebsd на другом ubuntu.

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25955/discussion-between-alexander-barakin-and-jamesmaynard).

Answer (score 0):

Git имеется? Им можно сравнить два любых файла, если они не в utf-16:

```
git diff file1 file2
```

Думаю, должно получиться как раз то, что ты хочешь.

Comment: вот вывод diff --git a/dpkglist.txt b/dpkglista.txt
index edcdfe2..51e9efe 100644
--- a/dpkglist.txt
+++ b/dpkglista.txt
@@ -1,684 +1,515 @@
далее я вижу просто вывод в консоль содержимого обеих файлов.

Comment: @JamesMaynard, возможно, я чего-то не понимаю, но почему `diff --git` вместо `git diff`? И, может, файлы разные из-за разного порядка строк?

Comment: комманду делал так git diff dpkglist.txt dpkglista.txt